# Нахождение глубины вложенности массивов Python

Tags: python

Столкнулся с проблемой решения задачи на [checkio](https://py.checkio.org/mission/how-deep/solve/)

Нужно найти глубину вложенности массива.
Моя реализация:

```
def how_deep(structure):
    flag = False
    count = 1
    for i in structure:
        if type(i) == tuple and not flag:
            count += how_deep(i)
            flag = True
    return count
```

На одном из тестов ошибка:
[image: ошибка]

Но запятые стоят не там, чтобы получить вложенность 3.
[image: разбор]

Answer (score 1):

По скобкам ориентируйтесь. Так должно быть понятнее

```
[
  1,
  [
    2
  ],
  [
    2,
    [
      3
    ]
  ]
]
```

Сколько видите отступов для тройки?

Ну, и решение может быть проще:

```
def how_deep(x):
    if x and isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
        return 1 + max(how_deep(i) for i in x)
    return 0
```

Comment: Ну если смотреть по скобкам да, понятно. Но тройка у нас идет просто (3) как целое число, и скобки в роли блока данных. Тогда как (3,) определяется как кортеж, ведь чтобы создать кортеж из одного элемента, нужно поставить запятую
Понял что isinstance больше к месту чем type.
Даже по условию задачи " А массив [1,2, [3]] - имеет глубину 2, т.к. один из элементов первого массива тоже массив." Но как тут получается эта глубина? Исходя что это список, понятно. Но в задачи то кортежи. Кстати, по той же самой причине, ваше решение не работает на 4 тесте.

Comment: В условии задачи написано про кортежи, но в примере вызова используются списки. Уточнять нужно у создателей тестов.

Answer (score -1):

Гораздо легче как мне кажется просто посчитать максимальное количество скобочек подряд.

```
def how_deep(structure):
    structure =str(structure)
    print(structure)
    s=0
    max=0
    for i in structure:
        if i=='(':
            s+=1
        print(s)
        if s>max:
            max=s
        if i ==')':
            s-=1
    return max
```

Можно заменить ( и ) на [ и ] если требуется искать массив, но на сайте работает именно вариант с ( и )